# swift touches - how to differentiate objects

Tags: swift, xcode6, touches

I'm still not comfortable with the touches func.

I'm able to use it and it works ok, but I need to understand it to get further on with my project.

Could someone please help me to understand how I can determine which object have been touched? I really want to understand what's going on so in the future I can do i.e. a switch statement based on the type of object that was touched...

So here's the typical code I uses:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
var touch : UITouch! = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
```

and here's what I want to be able to do:

```
switch touch {
case SKSpriteNode
   ....
case SKLabelNode
   ....
case SKNode
   ...

and so on...
```

Probably not correct, but this explain why I want to under how to be able to grab the information passed on to the touches func. Please point me in the right direction :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a section on this in the `UITouch` documentation:

[Working with touch events in SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006785-CH3-SW21).

You can get the location with `locationInNode` and then figure out what is at that location with `nodeAtPoint`.

Comment: Thanx, now, by doing `println("\(nodeAtPoint(location))")` I can see which node it is. Very good! But, how do I make a statement dependent on the node type? This did not work: `if nodeAtPoint(location) == SKLabelNode` (either "SKlabelNode")..

Comment: Use the Swift keyword `is` to check for class. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: So, here's my last struggle: now I know which node I'm touching, but how can I remove it from my scene using `removeFromParent()` ?

Comment: by fiddling around a little bit, I found out that I simply could do as followed: `nodeAtPoint(location).removeFromParent()` ... not sure if that's the right way, but it worked!